# django: ForeignKey and instance

Tags: django, foreign-keys, instance

I have a model

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
     slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True)

     def as_dict(self):
         return {
             'id': self.id,
             'name': self.name,
    }

class Event(models.Model):
 .....  
    title = models.CharField(_('titre'), max_length=100)      
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, verbose_name=_('machine'))
```

in the view, I have a function

```
 title= 'traction'
 macategorie= 'Atomisation'
 p = Event(title= untitre, calendar= macategorie)
```

I have the error :

> Event.calendar must be a "Calendar" instance

if I write

```
 p = Event(title= untitre, calendar_id= macategorie)
```

I have the error :

> invalid literal for int() with base 10; 'Atomisation'

if I write

```
print 'category', p.calendar_id
```

I display : Atomisation

It is not clear

How to write correctly calendar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look over the [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models)

You need to create a `Calendar` instance first.
Somewhat like this:

```
title= 'traction'
macategorie= 'Atomisation'
moncalendar = Calendar.objects.create(name="Atomisation", slug="atomisation")
p = Event(title= title, calendar= moncalendar)
```

**EDIT**
If you want to make sure, that the `Calendar` object is unique by the slug, try:

```
moncalendar, created = Calendar.objects.get_or_create( slug="atomisation")
moncalendar.name = "Atomisation"
moncalendar.save()
```

For this to work, you would need to change your model to something like this:

```
name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, blank=True, default="")
```

**or**

```
name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

**or** you would put it in an try-except and handle the case, where you try to add a Calendar with a same slug explicitly.
Somehow like this:

```
try:
    moncalendar = Calendar.objects.create(name="Atomisation", slug="atomisation")
except IntegrityError:
    moncalendar = Calendar.objects.get(slug="atomisation")
    moncalendar.name = "Atomisation"  # or handle differently as you like
    moncalendar.save()
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for more information.

Comment: I have the error : column slug is not unique <<class 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError and if I write p.save(), I display 'list' object has no attribute 'save'